unable to log out contents of a box structure for debugging, not sure how to debug debugging bug , pinescript ( obviously )
I found an interesting script that draws volume clusters that have a range, high and low, these are contained in a box structure with a user defined object as the parent.
my ultimate objective : extract the high and low value of all boxes contained in the user defined structure, the lookback to see which boxes to find would be 200 candles , we would keep getting new boxes within this 200 candle period and put them in some array to use for another function.
current status : attempting to console.log the boxes in the user defined structure, tried to google, brainstorm, use chatgpt, cannot be resolved. here are the structures that may aid your analysis / understanding :
here is the link to the original indicator by LuxAlgo , this page also includes the full code ; i cannot paste the full code as it is too long : https://www.tradingview.com/script/zVCsx5DL-Volume-Profile-with-Node-Detection-LuxAlgo/


type BAR
    float open   = open
    float high   = high
    float low    = low
    float close  = close
    float volume = volume
    int   index  = bar_index

type barData
    float [] barHigh
    float [] barLow
    float [] barVolume
    bool  [] barPolarity
    int   [] barCount

type volumeData
    float [] totalVolume
    float [] bullishVolume
    float [] bearishVolume
    int   [] endProfileIndex
    bool  [] peakVolume
    bool  [] troughVolume

type volumeProfile
    box         []  boxes
    chart.point []  pocPoints
    polyline        pocPolyline
    int             pocLevel
    int             vahLevel
    int             valLevel
    int             startIndex

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
// Variables
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------{

BAR bar = BAR.new()
BAR [] ltfBarData = array.new<BAR> (1, BAR.new())

var barData barDataArray = barData.new(
     array.new <float> (na), 
     array.new <float> (na), 
     array.new <float> (na), 
     array.new <bool>  (na), 
     array.new <int>   (na)
 )

volumeData volumeDataArray = volumeData.new(
     array.new <float> (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0.), 
     array.new <float> (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0.), 
     array.new <float> (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0.),
     array.new <int>   (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0 ),
     array.new <bool>  (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0.),
     array.new <bool>  (vp_profileNumberOfRows, 0.)
 )

var volumeProfile VP = volumeProfile.new(*your text*
     array.new<box>         (na),
     array.new<chart.point> (na),
     polyline.new           (na), na, na, na, na
 )

var float highestPrice = na
var float lowestPrice = na

so here i tried to access the box after much struggle, finally I got to a point where I am stuck because I don't see any output, and need help to access the box and get the box ranges into an array or some structure so I can use them elsewhere.  I'm also not sure how I would get all of the boxes, beginning 200 candles in the past, as boxes appear and disappear as more candles appear , so I need to capture those disappearing ranges of past boxes as well.
// Accessing the values of objects inside the array using the provided methods
box_bot = VP.boxes.last().get_bottom()
my_box = array.get(VP.boxes, array.size(VP.boxes) - 1)
box_left = my_box.get_left()
box_right = array.get(VP.boxes, array.size(VP.boxes) - 1).get_right()
the_same_box = array.last(VP.boxes)
box_top = the_same_box.get_top()

// Displaying the retrieved box values
boxDetails = "Box Properties: Top=" + str.tostring(box_top) + ", Bottom=" + str.tostring(box_bot) + ", Left=" + str.tostring(box_left) + ", Right=" + str.tostring(box_right)
label.new(x=bar_index, y=close, text=boxDetails, yloc=yloc.price)



if VP.boxes.size() == 0
    log.error("No boxes are present in VP.boxes array. Make sure boxes are being properly created and stored.")
else
    log.info("Number of boxes in VP.boxes array: " + str.tostring(VP.boxes.size()))

if array.size(VP.boxes) == 0
    log.error("The size of VP.boxes array is 0. Check if boxes are being added to the array.")

if VP.boxes.size() > 0
    lastBox = VP.boxes.last()
    log.info("Last box properties - Top: " + str.tostring(lastBox.get_top()) + ", Bottom: " + str.tostring(lastBox.get_bottom()) + ", Left: " + str.tostring(lastBox.get_left()) + ", Right: " + str.tostring(lastBox.get_right()))

if not na(my_box)
    log.info("my_box properties - Top: " + str.tostring(my_box.get_top()) + ", Bottom: " + str.tostring(my_box.get_bottom()) + ", Left: " + str.tostring(my_box.get_left()) + ", Right: " + str.tostring(my_box.get_right())
else
    log.error("Error accessing the box object from the array. 'my_box' is not a valid object.")

if box_top == na or box_bot == na or box_left == na or box_right == na
    log.error("Error retrieving box properties. One or more box properties are not available.")
else
    log.info("Box properties - Top: " + str.tostring(box_top) + ", Bottom: " + str.tostring(box_bot) + ", Left: " + str.tostring(box_left) + ", Right: " + str.tostring(box_right))



If you happen to have multiple scripts attached to the same chart, Log will select the topmost script sometimes thus showing you logs from a script that potentially has no logs at all. Check the log window's top row and make sure it shows the script that you want logs from.
